# Pop-up cards Turing complete?

Tags: reference-request, turing-machines, origami

I remember once having found an interesting paper demonstrating the pop-up card to be Turing complete. (In a similar fashion as ruler and compass being able to solve quadratic equations and origami cubic equations..) However, I can't seem to find the paper in question any more. Does anyone have a clue whether this might be a thing, have I remembered correctly?